# How do I remove the nulls out of the inner PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array from which I need to remove `null` values:

```
 [227] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
        [1] => 8
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
        [4] => 1
    )

)
```

I tried `array_filter($quantity);`

and also

```
foreach ($quantity as $key => $value) {
    if (is_null($value) || $value=="") {
        unset($quantity);
    }
}
```

and even tried the `foreach` with `$quantity[0]` and got Undefined offset 0. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

This works but what if i dont have the 227

```
foreach ($quantityval[227] as $key => $value) {
   if (is_null($value) || trim($value)=="") {  
      unset($quantityval[227][$key]);
  }
 }
```

Comment: I looked at that question and array_filter doesnt solve the issue...look at my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a nested array -- your foreach statement looks correct, but needs to check the inner arrays:

```
foreach ($quantity as $key => $item)
    foreach ($item as $key2 => $item2) {
        if (is_null($item2) || $item2=="") {
            unset($quantity[$key][$key2]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have values that are all white-space -- either regular spaces or possibly unicode characters. Try `trim($value) == ""`.

If that doesn't work `array_filter($array, "is_integer");` may do the trick.

Comment: Null values print like that, so it's not necessarily whitespace. `print_r(array(227 => array(3, 8, null, null, 1)));`

Comment: That's fair to point out, but when combined with the code he's tried, I can't think of anything else it could be besides whitespace.

Comment: updated my question with something thats hardcoded but what if i dont have the 227

Answer (score 1):

You updated solution works. The part about the hardcoded `227` is because `$quantity` is a multi-dimensional array (the extra closing parenthesis hinted that too). You need to do nested `foreach` for that.

```
foreach($bigArray as $bigKey => $smallArray)
{
  foreach($smallArray as $smallKey => $value)
  {
     if(is_null($value) || $value == "")
       unset($bigArray[$bigKey][$smallKey]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this for situations like that:

```
<?php
function filter_empty_recursive($arr)
{
    $keys = array_keys($arr);
    foreach($keys as $key)
    {
        if(is_array($arr[$key]))
        {
            $arr[$key] = filter_empty_recursive($arr[$key]);
        }
        else if(empty($arr[$key]))
        {
             unset($arr[$key]);
        }
   }
   return $arr;
}
```

It's a recursive function (so it can be a little brutal on memory with large nested array trees, and this particular one cannot handle infinite recursion (i.e.: circular reference).)  But with a non-infinite recursion, and reasonably sized nested array trees, it should work pretty well.  It can also be expanded to handle nested object properties as well, but that seemed outside scope.  The part where it decides if it's empty is that `if(empty())` so you can change that back to that is_null or empty string block.

(Edit: Adding really Low level explanation: loops through the array, if it finds an array inside of that array, it calls itself and repeats the process.)